# compute a xi-xj matrix in numpy without loops (by api calls)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

How to compute a xi-xj matrix in numpy without loops (by api calls)?

Here's what to start with:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(4)
xij = np.matrix([xi-xj for xj in x for xi in x]).reshape(4,4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reshaping the array, you can use the minus operator to calculate what you want

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(4)
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
xij = np.matrix(x.T - x)
```

Comment: You can skip the `reshape` step with the matrix class as all matrices are inherently 2D. `x = np.matrix(np.random.rand(4)); x - x.T`.

Comment: That was new to me. I tend to avoid using the `matrix` class since it can bite you quite hard if you are not careful (when *-operator is not doing what you expect it to).

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of broadcasting to subtract `x` as a column vector from `x` as a flat array and produce the matrix.

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(4)
```

Then:

```
>>> x - x[:,np.newaxis]
array([[ 0.        ,  0.89175647,  0.80930233,  0.37955823],
       [-0.89175647,  0.        , -0.08245415, -0.51219825],
       [-0.80930233,  0.08245415,  0.        , -0.4297441 ],
       [-0.37955823,  0.51219825,  0.4297441 ,  0.        ]])
```

If you want a matrix object (and not the default array object) you could write:

```
np.matrix(x - x[:,np.newaxis])
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use `np.subtract.outer`:

```
In [35]: x = np.random.rand(4)

In [36]: np.matrix([xi-xj for xj in x for xi in x]).reshape(4,4)
Out[36]: 
matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.45365177,  0.07227472, -0.05824887],
        [-0.45365177,  0.        , -0.38137705, -0.51190064],
        [-0.07227472,  0.38137705,  0.        , -0.13052359],
        [ 0.05824887,  0.51190064,  0.13052359,  0.        ]])

In [37]: -np.subtract.outer(x, x)
Out[37]: 
array([[-0.        ,  0.45365177,  0.07227472, -0.05824887],
       [-0.45365177, -0.        , -0.38137705, -0.51190064],
       [-0.07227472,  0.38137705, -0.        , -0.13052359],
       [ 0.05824887,  0.51190064,  0.13052359, -0.        ]])
```

(Note that the result is a numpy array, not a matrix.)